# How to remove an object from JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array. I want to delete the entry that have number `4` and return the left over array

```
$filters = '{"1":1,"2":2,"3":4}';
$fobj = json_decode($filters, TRUE);

foreach($fobj as $key => $value) 
{ 
if (in_array(4, $fobj)) {
 unset($fobj[4]);
  }
}
echo $filters = json_encode($fobj );
```

But this `echo` does not give me what I want. I want it to return something like this:

```
  {"1":1,"2":2}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're removing the fourth value of the array, not the value. Use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) instead

```
$filters = '{"1":1,"2":2,"3":4}';
$fobj = json_decode($filters, TRUE);
$search = array_search(4, $fobj);
if($search !== false) unset($fobj[$search]);
echo $filters = json_encode($fobj );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = array_search("4", $array);
unset($array[$index]);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.unset.php

That's all. Hope it helps!